# Granting privileges on MySQL

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

I have a MySQL database that I'm using for testing of a C# application. As a superuser, I enter the following 'query':

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testing.* TO 'Ubuntu'@'localhost';
```

to an affirmative message. Then, I log out of the database, log back in as Ubuntu, and run the following query on a localhost connection:

```
USE testing;
```

and receive this message:

```
ERROR 1044(42000): Access denied for user 'ubuntu'@'localhost' to database 'testing'
```

I've also run this query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testing.* TO 'Ubuntu'@'%';
```

with the same result.

What exactly am I missing? It seems like a fairly straightforward procedure...

Comment: On a side note, MySQL and operating system user accounts are distinct. You don't need to log in and out of Ubuntu to "change" the user you connect to MySQL with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe usernames are case-sensitive. In your queries, I see that you are granting permissions to  "Ubuntu" which is uppercase, but in your error message, "ubuntu" is lowercase.

Also, as pointed out by AMADANON Inc., you will most likely need to run the query

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

in order for the permissions to actually kick in.

Comment: Wondering if I can give credit to both you and Amadanon... both helped.

Comment: I think you can only mark one answer as correct. I'd rather Ricky gets credit than no-one at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, but thanks for letting me/us know that it worked!

Comment: @AMADANONInc. much appreciated! I will add your part into my answer as well, making it the "best answer" for anyone who may stumble upon this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

As Ricky pointed out (what is this, the mutual admiration society?!) usernames are case-sensitive, so the user `Ubuntu` is different from the user `ubuntu`